# web api call took too long to respond ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (TimedOut (0x274c))

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, socketexception, windows-firewall-api

I have created a very simple web API in C# and there is only one Get method. It's working fine from Visual Studio and IIS. But when I was trying to call it from client machine I was getting error XXX took too long to respond. Search google for XXX 8081 webAPI Get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I have enabled CORS, increased time out and tried several other steps from StackOverflow. When I checked with fiddler I got below error: [Fiddler] The connection to 'xxx.xxx.com' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.209.10.72:8081.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that I need to open a 8081 port from windows firewall on the server. I opened inbound rule for port 8081 and it resolved the issue. After that I was able to make webapi call from any client machine.